# Configuring Xdebug on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: php, macos, debugging, netbeans, xdebug

I would like to use Xdebug in conjunction with Netbeans on Mac OS X Mavericks. I have followed the instructions on this page: [NetBeans Wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug)

Hence I compiled Xdebug and debugclient, changed all the php.ini files (including the one in /private/etc/).

That's the configuration in php.ini:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
output_buffering=OFF
```

And yes, the path to xdebug.so is correct.

However, the phpinfo does not show any active installation of Xdebug. When I paste it on the Xdebug page for tailored installation instructions ([Xdebug Wizard](http://www.xdebug.org/wizard.php)), it tells me that Xdebug is not installed.

Now, to the interesting bit: if I paste the terminal output from `php -i`, it tells me that I'm already running the latest Xdebug version.

Also, when prompting the command `php -i | grep xdebug`, I get the following output (I past only the relevant section):

```
xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
```

→ remote_enable is off, despite the php.ini settings

When I try to debug a file in Netbeans (yes, I have re-started the Apache servers), the status Waiting for Connection(netbeans-xdebug) stays forever. In the Netbeans setting, the correct port is used.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: double check that you are editing the correct `php.ini` file: php -i|grep .ini

Comment: Thank you for this reply! Indeed, there was one more directory at `/opt/local/etc/php5/` where I created a new php.ini file with the relevant Xdebug settings. This solves the problem that xdebug.remote_enable is now ON.

However, in the phpinfo file Xdebug still does not appear, and Netbeans is still endlessly waiting for connection.

Comment: One strange thing that I noticed here: There are two directories holding an xdebug.so file: /opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so [in /opt/local/var/db/php5/xdebug.ini] and /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so [all php.ini files] --- EDIT: yet changing the former path to the latter makes no difference

Comment: This is because Mavericks comes with Xdebug bundeled. The one in the /opt/ path is the one you have compiled.